# Google analytics filter out file extension

Tags: regex, filter, google-analytics, analytics

I am noticing a few variations of the same page in my google analytics reportings e.g.

> /flash.php
>
> /flash/
>
> /flash

Does anyone know a (safe - won't mess up any data) filter to consolidate all urls into the `/flash` format (remove the extension and any trailling slashes)?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Your site will be better for search and usability, as well as solving this problem, if you consolidate the URLs for real — that is, make `/flash/` and `/flash.php` 301 redirect to `/flash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To merge these URLs into one, the solution is to use a **Search & Replace Filter**, or an **Advanced Filter**, depending on your usage for it.

For the case of only one page with this matter, the solution is to use the **S&R** filter:

1 - Go to your filters page, inside de profile you wish to apply the filter to

2 - Create a New Filter and select **Custom Filter** as the Filter Type

3 - Select **Search and Replace**

4 - Select **Request URI** as the Filter Field

5 - Type **\/flash.*** as the search string

6 - Type **/flash** as the replace string

Done, every URL that contains more than /flash will be merged into this one /flash one.

You can learn more about the search and replace filter [here](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55573)

---

For the case of many pages with this matter, the solution is to use the **Adv** filter:

1 - Go to your filters page, inside de profile you wish to apply the filter to

2 - Create a New Filter and select **Custom Filter** as the Filter Type

3 - Select **Advanced**

4 - Select **Request URI** as the Filter Field A

5 - Type **^(\/[\w\-]*)|^(\/)$** as the Extract A

6 - Select **Request URI** as the Output

7 - Type **$A1$A2** as the Constructor

Augusto Roselli - Web Analytist at [dp6](http://www.dp6.com.br)

Comment: Thanks augusto, but I have many pages and was hoping for some sort of regex or similar that doesn't require me to do this on a per page basis.

Comment: In that case, the way is to use an Advanced Filter, please check my answer above, I´ve updated it to suit these needs